# c# how to change tool transformation via script

Tags: c#, properties, position

I know how to add a text box or button via script , but I don`t know how to change the size and the position of the new (for example) button after creating it .
here is the code I used to create a text box when I press a button :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Text = "helloo";
        Controls.Add(txt);

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "I am a label";
        Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Size` and `Location` properties, or the individual `Top`, `Left`, `Width`, or `Height` properties.

Comment: I could not use these at first , so if anyone does not know what SLaks means I think this page would help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52aha046.aspx